# addItemListener with for-loop not possible

Tags: java, itemlistener

To shorten my code I started constructing lists with the components needed in my java project to access them with a simple for-loop.

As everything works I wanted to add ItemListeners to the components in the list:
`checkBoxes.get(0).addItemListener(){/*including code here*/}`
works totally fine, however I would like to set them with a loop as well. So I tried this:

```
for (int i=0; i<=10; i++){
    checkBoxes.get(i).addItemListener(new ItemListener){
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0){
           someMethod(i);
        }
    });
}
```

as the checkBoxes are supposed to trigger another method based on their index. I get the compiler error:

> Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

So I assume that I cannot add ItemListeners in this dynamic way? Is there a way around this?

After a second of testing it seems I cannot use `i` at all?

Comment: Will `someMethod(i)` treat each checkbox exactly the same ?. If so, you may not need to pass the index. If the method needs to know which button it is dealing with, then it may be best to check the action source, by finding the button in the list, and passing that, at run time. Hope this helps

Comment: It is supposed to be disabling a spinner with the same index in another list. Thanks for the suggestion however; I will keep that in mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the compiler says, `i` needs to be final.

To achieve this you could use an intermediate final variable in the loop.

```
for(int i=0; i<checkBoxes.size(); i++) {
    final int finalI = i;

    checkBoxes.get(i).addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0){
            someMethod(finalI);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Well thanks a lot! However you have been to fast answering... Accepted already; marked as that in 7 minutes :)

Comment: @geisterfurz007 You're welcome :)